# c++: request for member [function] in [class], which is of non-class type [class]

Tags: c++

while trying to compile this:

```
class DateTime
{
    private:
        Date d8;
        Time tym;
    public:
        DateTime(Date idate=Date(),Time itime=Time())
        {
            d8=idate;
            tym=itime;
        }
        void set(Date idate,Time itime)
        {
            d8=idate;
            tym=itime;
        }
        Time get_time()
        {
            return tym;
        }
        Date get_date()
        {
            return d8;
        }
        DateTime operator =(DateTime dt2())
        {
            DateTime x(dt2.get_date(),dt2.get_time());
            return x;
        }   
};
```

it will return the following error in the compiler :

```
266:19: error: request for member ‘get_date’ in ‘dt2’, which is of non-class type ‘DateTime (*)()’
```

BTW i don't event know what does the error mean.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo because you included superfluous parentheses after the argument `operator=(DateTime dt2)`. So, correctly the compiler thinks the function received a pointer-to-function, not an instance, and it correctly can't find the member in that totally different type.

Comment: Btw, that `operator=()` is wrong even if you fixed the signature, because it returns a copy of the argument that was passed in, which is pointless... since the caller could just use the one they would pass! `operator=()` should set `this` to the same state as the argument and return a reference to `this`, i.e. a `DateTime&`. With both, it seems you're not really thinking about what you're writing, and while enthusiasm to rush is admirable, it's not a good way to learn.

Comment: i didnt totally understand what you mean ... can you share some links about them so i dont bother you anymore?
sorry for asking this but can you give/share the fixed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In assignment operator you should return a reference to the same object:

```
DateTime & operator= (DateTime & dt2) // without () after dt2
{
    d8 = dt2.get_date();
    tym = dt2.get_time();

    return *this;
}
```